# Orbot can't load geoIP file

Tags: orbot, geoip

I get warnings in orbot log that says GEOIP file cannot be loaded from `/usr/share/tor`. I run cyanogenmod with root access for orbot. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you still have those issues? If not, how was it solved?